# Histogram Matching result is not similar with inputs

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-enhancement

I'm trying to do histogram matching on two matrixes.But result is not similar with input matrixes.I think it must similar with histogram of "log_ort_esitlenmis".

```
%Image enhancement'ta butun imge icin sag sutun
esitlenmis=histeq(a);
ort_esitlenmis=fft2(esitlenmis);
log_ort_esitlenmis=log(1+abs(ort_esitlenmis));

%Image enhancement'ta butun imge icin sol sutun 
ort=fft2(a);
angle_ort_1=angle(ort);% 1.ortogonal(fft) icin faz bilgisi tutma.
log_ort=log(1+abs(ort));

matched=imhistmatch(uint8(log_ort),uint8(log_ort_esitlenmis));
```

[This is the algorithm that I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJre0.jpg)

[Histograms of log_ort,log_ort_esitlenmis and mathced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgLIw.jpg)

Comment: It looks like the `uint8` cast looses most of the data. It's hard to follow without the input image. Can you add image `a` to your post?

Comment: Thanks for attention.I've solved the problem.The image `a` is a grey levet 8bit image.I've solved the problem by using `matched=imhistmatch(uint8(log_ort),uint8(log_ort_esitlenmis),256);`